# webpack view generated sourcemap

Tags: webpack, source-maps

I am writing a simple program using webpack.  I want to view the sourcemap (.map) file generated by webpack.  This is my webpack configuration

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve('src'),
    entry: {
        app: './app.jsx',
        vendor: './vendor.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/public/assets',
        sourceMapFilename: 'source.map'
    },
    resolve: {
        // only discover files that have those extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
            test: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
        },
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

However when I run build, I see only the app.js and vendor.js file.  No .map file is generated.  How do I view the .map file.

The second question is that even without the .map file Chrome is able to show the actual source files, how do it do this without the actual .map file?

Comment: 1Q: Ans   source map added in you file in bottom like this //# sourceURL = foo.js
2Q Ans :  with out souremap chrome is not able to show the actual source files

Comment: How do I get it to generate a different sourcemap?

Comment: output.sourceMapFilename
The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files. They are inside the output.path directory.

[file] is replaced by the filename of the JavaScript file.

[id] is replaced by the id of the chunk.

[hash] is replaced by the hash of the compilation.

Default: "[file].map"

Comment: Taking the above webpack file even when I run the build command I do not get the .map file.

Comment: try  below the  commands webpack-dev-server -d  or webpack -d

Comment: Still did not work, can you give me a sample webpack.config.js file that works with this.